# How to identify if request was sent using Selenium

Tags: selenium

Is there a way to identify if a HTTP request was send using Selenium?

For example if Selenium adds any request header, cookie or equivalent?

I tried looking at the User Agent, but it didn't reveal anything about Selenium:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
```

Comment: I don't believe there is, is there any reason why you need to do this?

Comment: @Arran I'd like my application to behave differently when it's used by Selenium. For example when it's the System Under Test (SUT).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` gets set if Selenium is being used:

```
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR => 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
```

Comment: Unfortunately ```HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR``` is used for detecting something else in our application (and the above doesn't appear to be unique to Selenium), so I won't mark this as the accepted answer yet, hoping there will be other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Selenium doesn't mark its requests with anything.